# Cannot load glade file with Gtk Builder. Gtk3#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#, glade

(Note: I did not write this code, it was generated from an addon project template)

When I try to use GTK Builder with Gtk# to load a glade file it throws an exception that the file must begin with an element.

**Error:**

```
GLib.GException has been thrown
Error on line 1 char 1: Document must begin with an element 
(e.g. <book>)
```

**MainWindow.glade:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
    <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.0" />
    <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
            <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
                <child>
                    <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="yalign">0.47999998927116394</property>
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Hello World! This button has been clicked 0 time(s).</property>
                    </object>
                    <packing>
                        <property name="expand">False</property>
                        <property name="fill">True</property>
                        <property name="position">0</property>
                    </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                    <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Click me!</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                    </object>
                    <packing>
                        <property name="expand">False</property>
                        <property name="fill">True</property>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                    </packing>
                </child>
            </object>
        </child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

**MainWindow.cs:**

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using UI = Gtk.Builder.ObjectAttribute;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    Builder builder;

    [UI] Gtk.Button button1;
    [UI] Gtk.Label label1;

    int clickedTimes;

    public static MainWindow Create ()
    {
        Builder builder = new Builder (null, "DiscordEditor.interfaces.MainWindow.glade", null);
        return new MainWindow (builder, builder.GetObject ("window1").Handle);
    }

    protected MainWindow (Builder builder, IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        this.builder = builder;

        builder.Autoconnect (this);
        DeleteEvent += OnDeleteEvent;

        button1.Clicked += onButtonClick;
    }

    protected void onButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs a)
    {
        clickedTimes++;
        label1.Text = string.Format ("Hello World! This button has been clicked {0} time(s).", clickedTimes);
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

I cannot see why this would be happening, unless it is a bug with GTK#3, as it is not fully released yet. I really would like to use GTK3 instead of GTK2, so what would anyone suggest?

**Edit:** I fixed it by opening the generated file, and saving it in GTKBuilder format.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I was modifying the glade file externally. It was because I was using a buffer that I zeroed and didn't properly set the actual file size. I didn't think it would matter but setting the eof correctly fixed the error. Not sure if it's the same on yours(not that it matters this many years later) but maybe it is due to something similar.  Seems to be a bug in gtk's glade reader not being very robust.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "setting the eof correctly"? And when you say "buffer" do you mean GtkTextBuffer?

Comment: @grandchild: When creating and over allocating a memory buffer, not a GtkTextBuffer, and zeroing it, one sets every element of the buffer to 0. Now if one then writes text to the buffer to create a glade ui file and writes it, the file may end with 0's which the glade ui file reader then mishandles it. I imagine what was going on was the parser came to the null characters and crapped out.

Comment: Okay, thanks. What I ended up doing was to copy the _contents_ of the xml file to a file with a _different name_ (with a text editor) and that magically fixed it. This seems related to the buffer problem that you were referring to, but it was weirder. Because now gui_new.glade worked, but if I deleted the original gui.glade and renamed the newly created gui_new.glade file back to gui.glade it would stop working again. Maybe something to do with file handles or Glade backup files... Really not sure. But using the new filename works, so I'm doing that.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed a similar problem for me, was copying the contents of the .glade file to a file with a new name and loading that one in the code. I can't explain why that would work, but it did.